# array in a react component is getting converted into a number(which is of length of that array) after pushing an object into it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

this is the code of App.js

```
import React,{useState,useRef,useEffect,createContext,useReducer} from 'react'
import "./App.css"
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar"
import Main from "./components/Main"
import Modal from "./components/Modal"

const Cart_ctx = createContext()
const App = () => {
  const[cartItemCount,setCartItemCount] = useState(0)
  const[modalOpen,setModalOpen] = useState(false)
  const[cartItems,setCartItems] = useState([])

  return (
    <>
     <Cart_ctx.Provider 
        value={{cartItemCount,
                setCartItemCount,
                modalOpen,
                setModalOpen,cartItems,setCartItems}}>
      <NavBar/>
      <Main cartItems={cartItems}/>
      <Modal modalOpen={modalOpen} cartItems={cartItems}/>
     </Cart_ctx.Provider >
    </>
  )
}

export default App
export {Cart_ctx}
```

and this is the code of another component  which returns jsx for single food item. i have passed product info object as props and this is the child of Main component

```
import React,{useContext,useState} from 'react'
import {Cart_ctx} from "../App"

const Item = ({product}) => {
  console.log(product);
  const cart_ctx = useContext(Cart_ctx)
  const [addItem,setAddItem] = useState(1)

  const handleclick=()=>{
    cart_ctx.setCartItemCount((prev)=>prev+addItem)
    cart_ctx.setCartItems((prev)=>prev.push(product)) // this line throws error when i clicking the ADD button twice
    setAddItem(1)
    console.log(cart_ctx.cartItems);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {
        <div className="item">
          <div className="item-info">
          <h2>{product.name}</h2>
          <p >{product.price}</p>
          <i>{product.discription}</i>
          </div>
          <div className="add-cart">
          <label htmlFor="qty"> Qty :</label>
          <input id="qty" type="number" value={addItem} onChange={(e)=>setAddItem(parseInt(e.target.value))}  min="1" max="5"/><br/>
          <button className="button" onClick={handleclick}> ADD </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Item
```

if i press the ADD button in above component twice ,react throws an error saying .push() is not a function, although it perfectly pushes the product object to the cartItem array the first time. when i log the cartItem value in other component it print the length of the cartItems array.

```
import React from 'react'

const Modal = ({modalOpen,cartItems}) => {

  console.log(cartItems);   //----->  (** this line logs exact length of the array **)
  if (!modalOpen) return null
  return (
    <div className="overlay">
      <div className="cart-modal">
        <h1>YOUR CART</h1>
        {cartItems.map((item)=>{
          return(
            <div>{item.name}</div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to suspect there is a problem with this line:

```js
cart_ctx.setCartItems((prev)=>prev.push(product))
```

The first thing to know is that the array `push` function returns the new length of the array. Second, the `setCartItems` function will set the state of cart items to be whatever the provided function returns. Since your provided function, `(prev)=>prev.push(product)`, returns the result of `push`, cart items becomes a number instead of an array.

What you actually want is for the inner function return an array, which you can do by creating a new array:

```js
cart_ctx.setCartItems((prev) => [...prev, product])
```

I sometimes forget this too about the `setWhatever` methods; to help me remember, I mentally think of them as assignment operators. Doing `cartItems = cartItems.push(product)` doesn't make sense, but `cartItems = [...cartItems, product]` does.